# How to spilt pandas series based on list of dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas series with datetime index:

```
2020-06-09 10:20:00     1
2020-06-09 10:25:00     2
2020-06-09 10:30:00     3
2020-06-09 10:35:00     4
2020-06-09 10:40:00     5
2020-06-09 10:45:00     6
2020-06-09 10:50:00     7
2020-06-09 10:55:00     8
2020-06-09 11:00:00     9
2020-06-09 11:05:00    10
2020-06-09 11:10:00    11
2020-06-09 11:15:00    12
2020-06-09 11:20:00    13
2020-06-09 11:25:00    14
2020-06-09 11:30:00    15
2020-06-09 11:35:00    16
2020-06-09 11:40:00    17
```

And dataframe with date ranges:

```
    start                   end
0   2020-06-09 10:21:00     2020-06-09 10:53:00
1   2020-06-09 10:42:00     2020-06-09 10:58:00
```

I want to get a collection of values for all date ranges:

```
[
 [2,3,4,5,6,7],
 [6,7,8]
]
```

Is there a way to do this faster than iterating over the dataframe with dates like this:

```
for x in df.iterrows():
  series[(series.index > x.start) & (series.index < x.end)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If use [`Series.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.loc.html):

```
L = [series.loc[s:e].tolist()  for s, e in df[['start','end']].to_numpy()]
```

it working same like `>=` and `<=` comparison:

```
L = [series[(series.index >= s) & (series.index <= e)].tolist() 
                                  for s, e in df[['start','end']].to_numpy()]
```

---

But if need comapre by higher and lower then need:

```
L = [series[(series.index > s) & (series.index < e)].tolist() 
                                  for s, e in df[['start','end']].to_numpy()]
```